# Hostinger Server with LiteSpeed, should I activate and switch from WP Cache Premium to Lite Speed Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins

so I have my websites now in Hostinger. I see they use LiteSpeed (server side) I have purchased Wp Fastest Cache Premium. Now I am not sure if I should switch to LiteSpeed...

maybe is "more compatible?"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post comparing both LiteSpeed Cache and Fastest Cache.
https://blog.litespeedtech.com/2020/08/24/litespeed-cache-vs-wp-fastest-cache/

Both LiteSpeed Cache for WordPress and WP Fastest Cache are strong contenders, but LiteSpeed is a clear winner when it comes to the ability to cache more scenarios (eCommerce, logged-in users, situations requiring cache varies, etc.).

If your site is simple, then either one should work for you.

Best